# DFP code in Chrome not working

Tags: google-dfp

I have problem with my DFP code in Chrome.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var googletag = googletag || {};
   googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
   (function() {
       var gads = document.createElement('script');
       gads.async = true;
       gads.type = 'text/javascript';
       var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
       gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
           '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
       var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
   })();
</script>
<div>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        googletag.defineSlot('/00000000/970x90_ads_block', [970, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-1390508789385-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
    });
</script>
<!-- 970x90_ads_block -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-0000000000000-0' style='width:970px; height:90px;'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
       googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-000000000000-0');       });
    </script>
 </div>
```

It works fine in Firefox and IE, but in Chrome I receive error in line 38 in www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js

[image: error in Chrome dev console]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! Problem was in in AdBlock plugin in Chrome. I completely forgot about it.